# Should I edit my question or ask a new one, if an answer is correct, but I need now an alternative for older version of MySQL?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748778/how-to-left-join-with-first-matching-row-and-fill-the-rest-with-null) question and I found a perfect solution, but then I realized that my company uses an older MySQL version than my local one and part of the code doesn't work. So now I would like to ask about alternatives for code placed in answer, but I'm not sure about that...

Should I:

1. Edit my question and add at the end something like "**EDIT** I use MySQL 5.7 "
   (with this one, answers for all versions of MySQL will be in one topic, but the solution of the problem is already there, so the point now isn't to look for a new solution, but just to translate of an existing one)

BENEFIT: If someone will look for "How to left join with first matching row and fill the rest with null?", he will see how to do that in every version of MySQL.

2. Ask about code alternatives for `LAG... OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)` in MySQL 5.7?
   (with this I can open a new question about a specific problem, where the previous solution is just an example to translate)

BENEFIT: If someone will look for "What's the `LAG... OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)` alternative in MySQL 5.7, a new question will perfectly fit his needs.

So both solutions can be quite beneficial, but which one is better in this situation?

Comment: Never edit your question and announce that you've edited it by using a bold word like **EDIT**. People can see the edit history of your question if they really want to know when you edited it, and, as Larnu says in their answer, you shouldn't be adding answer-changing information after it's been answered anyway.

Comment: I would want to stress that you need to take a little care how you word your followup question because you wouldn't be the first to get advice on meta, ask a new question and then see that question downvoted or even close voted for being a little too confident that everyone using the site has seen you post on meta. Don't make it read unresearched and don't make it look like you're demanding a list of alternative solutions to your original question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Editing the question would invalidate your existing answer, which is severely frowned upon. I would suggest first searching on how to implement the functionality on an older version [of MySQL] (there are answers out there, that I am 100% certain of).

If you then fail to implement those solutions, ask a new question, showing your attempts, and explain why they didn't work and ensure you **tag your version**. Cite the prior answer you have as well, to show the solution you have that doesn't work either, and explain why you can't use that on (one of) your environments due to the age of your product.

Or, of course, you could update the version of MySQL. ;)

Comment: I disagree, @AlexeiLevenkov, invalidating even your own answer with an edit isn't a good idea. It could at best just mean that the old, now invalid answer is "noise", and at worst could therefore attract downvotes to an answer was *was* useful; because it is no longer correct. If the OP *knew* the answer to the new problem, they could expand the answer, but they don't so they would likely need to delete their answer instead; I'm not a fan of the idea of promoting deletion of useful answers.

Answer (score 11):

You can just ask the answerer if they could add a addendum to include a solution for older versions of MySQL. That way everyone wins.

Comment: The question author self-answered the question, so I suspect they have already asked themselves.

Comment: @IanCampbell they say the solution is based on a snipped provided by someone else. That someone can also suggest a version where the facility isn't there.

Comment: I don't think the answerer will feel like winning though -- for example, if there are like 10+ versions to add.

Comment: @holydragon usually there'll be only two versions of the query; one for the newer version (specifically v8 and above for MySQL) and the other is any version before that. Especially when it's about the `LAG()` function alternatives.

Comment: I agree because this way, it is easier to find a solution for the given problem.

Comment: I tend to be a bit annoyed when the OP responds to a good answer of mine with "what about this other thing ...?"  I often respond to those anyway, but I don't consider it winning.

Comment: If it is self answered, then OP should have simply updated their answer to include a version of the same syntax for the older version, so we skip the round trip of asking for a different versioned answer in the first place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger remember that the asker question is just an excuse to extract knowledge out your brain and into the whole internet. Don't think about the asker, think about future readers.

Comment: @Braiam, I always have other readers in mind, but that does not make it less rude -- or less of a breach of protocol, if you prefer -- for an OP to change the question or expand its scope after it has already been answered.  Doing that by asking additional questions in comments is even worse than doing it by editing the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger how is rude/breach of protocol to tell that your solution is incomplete? If you are thinking about the future reader that has the same issue, shouldn't you consider the most likely scenarios?

Comment: @Braiam, I am speaking of Q&As such as are the topic of this one: "an answer is correct, but I need [something different / extra]".  It is an entirely different thing if my answer does not respond fully to the question actually posed, or if the OP wants clarification of something in it.  As I already described, I am talking about cases that amount to changing the question after it has been answered.  We do not find that acceptable when it is done by editing the question, and there is no reason why we should find it any more acceptable when it is done via comments.

Comment: @JohnBollinger well, that's not the case we are discussing anyways. Here is the same question, just that the answerer presumed that there was some facilities that are only for versions X onward. Is not asking an entirely different question. Someone could post the answer for previous versions and still be a correct answer.